# Android Database Creation

Tags: android

i have created a class for creating database in android, but there are some compilation errors in this.....
I am not able to identify why these errors are coming.. My Code is

```
public DbHelper(Context ctx) { 
        try {
            db = ctx.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            try {
                db =
                    ctx.createDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, 0,
                        null);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                db = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

When i am opening database with "Context" object , it is giving me error that "openDatabase" method is undefined.  ?

Comment: You need  to add openDatabase() in your class by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Check out this link-
```

> http://knightswhocode.com/wordpress/2011/02/android-sqlite-crud-methods-2/

This link explains open and create database methods and how to create database class. Similarly you need to create your class.Try using it!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the top of DbHelper() constructor:

```
this.ctx=ctx //where ctx is the object of Context class (Context ctx);
```

Check it.

Comment: Have you declared the instance of Context class at the top of your DBHelper class: **Context ctx;**

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what lines give what errors exactly?

An Android [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) object does not have an `openDatabase` method, it does however have an `openOrCreateDatabase` method, did you mean to use that instead? Or did you want to use the static `openDatabase` method on [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). so `db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(....);`